# Extend JavaScript (Vuejs3) proxies with another method

Tags: vuejs3, javascript-proxy

Vue3 uses proxies to wrap object data properties.

I have several of these objects where I'd like to add additional functionality to the proxy itself, namely watch `get` for certain scenarios. Is there a way to extend the `proxy` object created by Vue, or is it too late because all of that functionality has to be passed in the callback when the `proxy` object is created?

I'd like to avoid wrapping a proxy in another proxy, if that's even a possibility.

---

*Update*

I did try wrapping my object in a Proxy. This caused very bad things to happen when Vue added its Proxy, including something I'm still not sure should be possible - stepping through each line in debugger, as soon as a line tried to access the data property the currently running function would simply not be running any longer. No errors, doesn't freeze the application, not even a warning level message. The application simply doesn't make it past that line in the current function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar needs. I had my own proxies but the issue was that they were not reactive and any changes to the underlying target won't be watched. I managed to make my proxy reactive the following way:

```js
const target = {}

const reactiveProxy = reactive( new Proxy( reactive(target), { /*...*/ }) )
```

Hope this works for your use case too.